# what does the cursor() method of GAE Query class return if the last result was already retrieved?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

From the Google App Engine documentation:

"cursor() returns a base64-encoded cursor string denoting the position in the query's result set following the last result retrieved."

What does it return if the the last result retrieved IS the last result in the query set? Wouldn't this mean that there is no position that can 'follow' the last result retrieved? Therefore, is 'None' returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all results have been consumed, the cursor just points to *that* position.

In other words, the cursor points to where *new results* would appear if you were to add more items to the datastore. From the [Datastore Queries documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Query_Cursors):

> A cursor marks a location within a query's index from which to begin the next scan for results. As such, it does not represent a relative offset within the query's result list, but rather the position following a specific result. If the query's results change between uses of a cursor, only those changes that follow the cursor position in the index will affect the results of subsequent retrievals.

The `cursor()` method will never return `None`.

Comment: dumb question.. but what precisely do you mean by "that" position?

Comment: @HorseloverFat: positions in the query set; so pointing to just after the last result.

Comment: is it the last position, or the position just after the last result?

Comment: seems to be two different opinions here unless I'm not understanding?

Comment: @HorseloverFat: *A cursor marks a location within a query's index from which to begin the next scan for results*, so *after*.

Answer (score 3):

There's still a cursor, even if the last result is retrieved. The query class doesn't know that, in any case: it knows what you've had already, but it doesn't know what else is still to come. The cursor doesn't represent any actual result, it's simply a way of resuming the query later. In fact, it's possible to use a cursor even in the case where you reach the end of the data set on your initial query, but later updates mean that new items are now found on a subsequent request: for example, if you're ordering by last update time.

(Good username, btw: gotta love some PKD.)

Comment: ok. would this evaluate to true if I reached the end of my current set of query results? `cursor == my_query.cursor()` (assume I just fetched from `my_query`, and `cursor` variable was set before that happened).

Comment: @HorseloverFat: If `cursor` points to the same position; perhaps if you used it as an end cursor for the query, then yes.

Comment: what about if I had used `cursor` as the start cursor for a fetch on a query, and that fetch had retrieved the last result from my set. would `cursor == my_query.cursor()` evaluate to true?